# Android: Error passing data from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

Hi I am new to Android Programming.

I create an application with tab layout and swipeable views following this link:
[source](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

I have 1 activity file `TabMainActivity.java` and 3 fragment classes under the the activity file.

My `TabMainActivity.java` references this xml file:

```
 main_menu.xml
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager   
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/pager"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

The error i encounter is when I try to pass data from `TabMainActivity.java` to `MyLockerFragment.java` (fragment file).

TabMainActivity.java-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
     String email = "tv.nguyen.2011@sis.smu.edu.sg";
     Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
     bundle.putString("email", email);
     MyLockerFragment fragobj=new MyLockerFragment();
     fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
  }//end of of onCreate method
```

MyLockerFragment.java-

```
 public class MyLockerFragment extends Fragment {
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mylocker,  
                     container, false);
            Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
            String email=bundle.getString("email");
}
```

Error is at this line: `String email=bundle.getString("email");`

Am I missing out something fundamental?

Comment: "_Error is at this line..._" And what error would that be? Post the logcat output in your question please.

Comment: Hi i get a java.lang.NullPointerException error at the line:

Comment: When you added the "email" to your bundle before passing it to your fragment, was `email` initialized? This line `bundle.putString("email", email);` where did you create the `email` variable?

Comment: a separate string variable,nothing wrong with that

Comment: Can you edit your `TabMainActivity.java` code to show how and where you declared and initialized that string variable?

Comment: String email = "tv.nguyen.2011@sis.smu.edu.sg";
     Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
     bundle.putString("email", email);
         
      MyLockerFragment fragobj=new MyLockerFragment();
      fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

Comment: Please edit your question to add this code, not as a comment.

Comment: @user2445971 u got ur answer is still waiting?

Comment: still waiting , please help

Answer (score 0):

In TabMainActivity.java :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
     String email = "tv.nguyen.2011@sis.smu.edu.sg";
     Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
     bundle.putString("email", email);
     MyLockerFragment fragobj=new MyLockerFragment();
     fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

     //You needed to add this line to the fragment Activity onCreate() method(othwewise the getArguments() would return null):

     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragobj).commit();


  }//end of of onCreate method
```

In MyLockerFragment.java :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String email = getArguments().getString("email");  

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mylocker,  
                     container, false);          

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Hi I tried the above code but I keep getting a java.lang.NullPointerException at 

 Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
  String email=bundle.getString("email");